# Search in Japan Language in Salesforce using SOQL?

Tags: community, salesforce1-app

I have create a custom lookup in my salesforce one app. when i tried to enter a search term in Japan language it won't get any result and if i type in english it show results.

Any Solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you try to turn this setting on and check the results? Setup=>Customize=>Search=>Search Settings=>Enable Search Optimization if your Content is Mostly in Japanese, Chinese, or Korean

Comment: Vikas since this is related to SOQL, can you post an example query with the japanese search term? Did you try using the schema explorer or some tool to check if the search term is indeed valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a field Account name (local) [in case of Account] is associated with SObject which will store information in local language, run SOQL on that field it will give results. Every object has this field available.

Hope this helps